# How to ignore unknown namespaces with C# XmlReader?

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, xmlreader

I'm trying to read string XML snippets from input using the **XmlReader**, manipulate the XDocument and output the result as a string.
In case there is a reference to unknown XML namespace, I just want this reference to be kept, not modified in any way.
Note I don't know the list of possible namespaces, so creating manually namespace whitelist is not an option.
I'm targeting the **UWP** platform, so XmlTextReader cannot be used here.

Sample of the input XML document:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Sample of the expected output XML document:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
  <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
  </VisualState.Setters>    
</VisualState>
```

My current code for parsing the XML:

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
{
    using (XmlReader xtr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    {
        return XDocument.Load(xtr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the issue is this throws an exception? You're a little stuck here as the XML fragment isn't a valid XML document without the missing namespace declarations. `XmlTextReader` had a mode that turned off namespace support (and allowed a colon as a name character), but I don't think you'll find that anywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Not ignoring them but simply accepting whenever one is present.

```
xml.Load(fil);
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
var nsNode = xml.DocumentElement.Attributes.GetNamedItem("xmlns");
var nsurl = (nsNode != null) ? nsNode.Value : "";

ns.AddNamespace("ns", nsurl);
```

If you now prefix all your XPaths (if any) with "ns:" and pass the namespace manager as argument, you should be fine:

```
var nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("//ns:whatever", ns);
```

**Edit:** This is using XmlDocument, not XDocument, but should get you going too.

Comment: Don't think this will help. Based on the XML in the question, this will throw an exception at `xml.Load`.